# Encoding type error - python 3.x

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x, encoding, import

I've got a problem with the encoding type of the file that i'm importing ( it contains polish special characters ). How do I make it work?

The error says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/Denis/Dysk Google/scripts/python/napisy/napisy", line 6, in <module>
    str = inputfile.read() #name for the file
  File "D:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 2: character maps to <undefined>
```

part that there is a problem with:

```
inputfilename = "a.txt"
outputfilename = inputfilename[0:-4]+"_fixed"+".txt"

inputfile = open(inputfilename, 'r')

str = inputfile.read() #name for the file

newstring = str.replace("œ", "s").replace("ê","e").replace("³","l").replace("¹","a").replace("¿","z").replace("ñ","n").replace("Ÿ","z").replace("æ","c")

outputfile = open(outputfilename, "w")
outputfile.write(newstring)
outputfile.close()
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3? I suspect Python 2, but please verify.

Comment: It's python 3 (title).

Comment: Specify the correct encoding in the `open` call. Your system apparently has a default encoding of cp1252, but the file is encoded in some other encoding.

Comment: oh thanks! I tried with adding encoding to 'open' call but i didn't think about cp1250. Shame on me thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try 'cp1250' as encoding:

```
import codecs
content = None
with codecs.open('file-name', 'r', encoding='cp1250') as f:
    content = f.read()

print(content)
```

if this fails, you may also try ISO-8859-2 encoding

Comment: encoding cp1250 works :) i tried with utf-8, iso etc... but it didn't work. I should listen to the errors more :) Thanks anyway